# Interactive plot with ipyvidgets and matplotlib on binder produces static images

Tags: python, matplotlib, interactive, mybinder

I'm trying to share a github repo on [binder](https://mybinder.org/). Locally, my interactive plot using matplotlib and @interact works ok. On binder it works half way. Same code adds static images to the cell output in binder notebook when slider value changes.

Question: how to fix binder behavior and make an interactive plot?

git repository https://github.com/queezz/Complex_Numbers

My notebook looks like this:

```py
%pylab inline
```

```py
from ipywidgets import interact, widgets
```

```py
x = np.linspace(0,np.pi,100)
@interact
def plot_interactive(a=widgets.FloatSlider(min=1, max=10, val=1)):
    plot(x,np.sin(x*a))
    gca().set_aspect('equal')
    ylim(-1.1,1.1)
```

Screenshot from binder:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a good working example:
https://github.com/Kapernikov/ipywidgets-tutorial

The gist of it is to use `%matplotlib widget` and `@widgets.interact`.

It seems that usage of `%pylab inline` is discouraged now, see [this git issue](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/5071/#issuecomment-34547616).

I copy a part of the code from the tutorial which produces the same result as wanted in the question.

```py
%matplotlib widget
import ipywidgets as widgets
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
```

```py
# set up plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6, 4))
ax.set_ylim([-4, 4])
ax.grid(True)

# generate x values
x = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 300)


def my_sine(x, w, amp, phi):
    """
    Return a sine for x with angular frequeny w and amplitude amp.
    """
    return amp*np.sin(w * (x-phi))


@widgets.interact(w=(0, 10, 1), amp=(0, 4, .1), phi=(0, 2*np.pi+0.01, 0.01))
def update(w = 1.0, amp=1, phi=0):
    """Remove old lines from plot and plot new one"""
    [l.remove() for l in ax.lines]
    ax.plot(x, my_sine(x, w, amp, phi), color='C0')
```

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to get @queez's answer that uses 'interact' to work today (later updated in early 2023 is below); however, the ipywidgets documentation presently includes [a matplotlib example](https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/Using%20Interact.html?highlight=matplotlib#Flickering-and-jumping-output), which uses 'interactive', that I was able to take and adapt @qqueezz's [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67816794/8508004) to get it working. This seems to be a much more streamlined route to make an interactive plot.

```py
#%matplotlib inline # from the example in the documentation. but doesn't seem necessary in current JupyterLab 3.1.11 or the classic notebook available now https://github.com/fomightez/communication_voila
from ipywidgets import interactive
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def my_sine(x, w, amp, phi):
    """
    Return a sine for x with angular frequency w and amplitude amp.
    """
    return amp*np.sin(w * (x-phi))

def f( w, amp, phi):
    plt.figure(2)
    x = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 300)
    plt.plot(x, my_sine(x, w, amp, phi), color='C0')
    #plt.ylim(-5, 5)
    plt.grid(True) #optional grid
    plt.show()

interactive_plot = interactive(f, w=(0, 10, 1), amp=(0, 4, .1), phi=(0, 2*np.pi+0.01, 0.01))
#output = interactive_plot.children[-1]
#output.layout.height = '450px'
interactive_plot
```

You can go to the repo [here](https://github.com/fomightez/communication_voila), launch a session by choosing the `launch binder` badge to the right of 'Start with the matplotlib & widget demo as a notebook' under 'Direct links to start out in notebook mode:'.
Or click [here](https://mybinder.org/v2/gh/fomightez/communication_voila/master?filepath=notebooks%2Fmatplotlib_widget_control.ipynb) to launch directly into that notebook via MyBinder.

---

**UPDATE**:
Later (early 2023), I found queez's code from [Kapernikov: Ipywidgets with matplotlib](https://kapernikov.com/ipywidgets-with-matplotlib/) did work with `interact` in JupyterLab using `ipympl`.
Not following yet what changed; however, wanted to note.