# How do I address No module named 'IPython.html' error?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

Very new to this. I'm in Jupyter Notebook, following instructions  to make [interactive visualizations](https://www.dominodatalab.com/blog/interactive-dashboards-in-jupyter). I'm using the following code, taken directly from the site:

```
from IPython.html.widgets import *
t = arange(0.0, 1.0, 0.01)

def pltsin(f):
    plt.plot(x,sin(2*pi*t*f))
    plt.show()
    
interact(pltsin, f=(1,10,0.1))
```

When I try this, I get the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [3], in <cell line: 10>()
      6     print(text.value)
      8 text.on_submit(handle_submit)
---> 10 from IPython.html.widgets import *
     11 t = arange(0.0, 1.0, 0.01)
     13 def pltsin(f):

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'IPython.html'
```

What's the problem here? Is there something I've failed to install? Thanks in advance for the assistance.

Comment: Did you install it? `pip install ipython`

Comment: That code looks out of date.  In current IPython, the module is `ipywidgets`: so try `from  ipywidgets import *`, or maybe better, import just what you need, i.e. `from ipywidgets import interact`.

Comment: When I run this it's returning a list of "Requirement already satisfied".

Comment: @slothrop it looks like that line worked! Now it's giving me trouble on the `arange` command.

Comment: That's a numpy function, so try `import numpy as np` then refer to the function as `np.arange`.

Comment: General note: Python, and particularly libraries around data handling and visualisation, evolve over time, so it's best to use tutorials which were written or updated recently.  This one is nearly 7 years old...however, the missing numpy import can't be blamed on that :)

Comment: I'm going to post an 'answer' so I can include code. I really am just trying to point you to updated documentation and methods that require variations on what you have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a companion to my comment under the OP so that I can add code.
Here is an updated version of the code you have that will work. It is largely based on [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69182917/8508004) which notes that now [the ipywidgets documentation features](https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/Using%20Interact.html?highlight=matplotlib#Flickering-and-jumping-output) `interactive` and not `interact` with the matplotlib example. (I was unsure about the `x` in the Domino Labs code you linked and so you may want to look at what I did in regards to that.)

```py
from ipywidgets import interactive
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

t = np.arange(0.0, 1.0, 0.01)


def pltsin(f):
    plt.plot(t,np.sin(2*np.pi*t*f))
    plt.show()

interactive_plot = interactive(pltsin, f=(1,10,0.1))
interactive_plot
```

**Try it out in your browser without installing anything**.

To try it out in a session backed by MyBinder where the environment already has ipywidgets and numpy installed, click [here](https://mybinder.org/v2/gh/fomightez/3Dscatter_plot-binder/master?urlpath=git-pull%3Frepo%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fgist.github.com%252Ffomightez%252F87e01e3014b1d2ec9c201040d7c16ac3%26urlpath%3Dlab%252Ftree%252F87e01e3014b1d2ec9c201040d7c16ac3%252Fupdated_interactive_plot_for_so69182917.ipynb) and then choose `Run` > `Run All Cells` from the main menu to run the code and see the interactive plot.

Answer (score -1):

Run `! pip install IPython` within the jupyter notebook.

The ! tells the notebook to run the command in bash, just make sure the pip you are using is the same interpreter the notebook is using

Comment: When I run this it's returning a list of "Requirement already satisfied". How do I ensure the pip is the same interpreter?

Comment: @Osei-Asante, please no longer suggest using an exclamation for use with `pip` or `conda`. Magic commands were added in the last few years to deal with the issues that can happen when an exclamation point is used to attempt installation inside a Jupyter notebook. See [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/why-users-can-install-modules-from-pip-but-not-from-conda/10722/4?u=fomightez) for more about the modern magics **that insure installation occurs in the environment backing the notebook**.